# How to mock Context using Mockito?

Tags: android, bluetooth, mockito, android-wifi, android-context

I'm using Context to access system level services like WifiManager and BluetoothManager. How to mock this getApplicationContext() using Mockito?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's have a look at the following class: [MockContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html)

If you need more insight, check the [Official Testing Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html) page

Comment: Can you add a little more answer to your answer?

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296849/2425030

Comment: Less than unhelpful

Answer (score 42):

```
    Context context = mock(Context.class);
```

Comment: It looks like it's not working in newer version of Mockito. Mockito forbids mocking types which have complex contracts or easy to construct by other means. It throws the exception `'context' is mocking 'class android.content.Context'. Don't mock android components, as they have lots of state and complex behavior - use the real thing. A Context can be obtained from ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() in Robolectric tests, or from InstrumentationRegistry in emulator tests..`

Answer (score 26):

If you want to get the context with `Kotlin` and `Mockito`, you can do it in the following way:

```
mock(Context::class.java)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't mock types you don't own. But why? let's say you are mocking a third-party library, if the maintainers of that library made changes, then your tests will be executed because it is a mock and you think everything is okay, but it is not because there are changes that you are not aware of, and things can go badly.

Comment: This is what integration tests are for. Mocks are used to say "let's assume, this other object (being mocked here) behaves in this and that fashion, does my SUT work as intended?" In fact, your argument also applies to your own code. If that changes, your mocks don't necessarily change and you have the same problem.