# How can one write an Integration Test that requires an Android Context?

Tags: java, android, integration-testing

For example, testing input/output to an image file. To create the file, the following code is used (summary):

```
 File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
 File image = File.createTempFile("tempImage",".jpg",storageDir);
 mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
 mCurrentPhotoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.fileprovider",image);
 File photoFile = image;
```

When I try to write an integration test using this code to create a file, I have issues with the `getExternalFilesDir` and `this` (which is a context). How can I effectively test without having an activity or context to pass? Can I generate one?

Comment: Are you using Mockito? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063848/how-to-mock-context-using-mockito

Comment: I am not - Android Studio - if that's helpful information.

Comment: That's an IDE. You can test your app using Mockito - that was my question - what testing framework do you have?

Comment: No testing framework - do you have a summary of how that integrates/works? Or should I just google it and do some research?

Comment: Mock testing is different than integration testing, so I'm probably leading you on the wrong path, anyway

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Something to look into then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an instrumentation test, `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` returns a `Context` for the package being tested.