# Can't initialize lateinit property (class) properly in test using Mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, mockito

[Class using "context"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1ueX.png)

[So in MainActivity.kt everything is great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMw1H.png)

[But in test it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UcfG.png)

```
package com.example.testwork

import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

class PrefManagerTest {

    lateinit var prefManager: PrefManager

    @Test
    fun getUsername() {
        prefManager = PrefManager(this)
        prefManager.setUsername("name")
        Assert.assertEquals("name", prefManager.getUsername())
    }
}
```

[In general I'm trying to test my function in PrefManager.kt, which gives name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDpdC.png)
[PrefManager.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyel7.png)

```
package com.example.testwork

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences

class PrefManager(context: Context?) {
    //Shared Pref Mode
    val PRIVATE_MODE: Int = 0

    //SharedPref FileName
    private  val PREF_NAME: String? = "SharedPreferences"
    private val IS_LOGIN: String? = "is_login"


    val pref: SharedPreferences? = context?.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = pref?.edit()

    fun setUsername(username: String?){
        editor?.putString("username", username)
        editor?.commit()
    }

    fun getUsername(): String?{
        return pref?.getString("username", "")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

1. Java:

   Context context = mock(Context.class);
2. Kotlin:

   mock(Context::class.java)

[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063848/how-to-mock-context-using-mockito)